# How to use AWS S3 buckets, for video streaming without cloudfront

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am trying to develop a video streaming platform. I spent my budget on S3, and now want to fetch the videos. I want the videos to buffer and found out tutorials in which users could send the chunks of data using readable streams, buffers and pipes, for videos stored on the localhost. How do I do the same for the videos stored on S3?

I'm using react for front end and node js for backend

I was able to buffer the videos stored in my home directory. I want to figure out how can we do the same for vidoes from S3.

Comment: "I want the videos to buffer" What specifically do you mean by this?

Comment: Like how buffering happens in YouTube, I want to fetch "partial content" and the send it to the video player of react. My only issue is, I don't understand whether I would have to wait for the entire file would be downloaded from the S3 to the backend.

Comment: @Smeet No, you wouldn't is the short answer. Check my answer here regarding streaming (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70681075/4800344) and then google 'S3 byte range fetch' :)

Comment: `s3
    .getObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: filename,
      Range: 'bytes=0-20582912',
    })
    .createReadStream()
    .pipe(res);`

I tried this but it still has latency issues

Answer (score 1):

For any normal HTTP server that supports ranged requests (which includes S3), you don't have to do anything special.

The browser will automatically request the data it needs to play the video, and will not download the entire video if it isn't being watched.  Additionally, when you seek into the video, the browser will skip ahead later in the file and request the data it needs.

Upon initial connection, you will see the browser get data from the server faster than it can play, but this is normal and ensures a nice playback experience.  If the browser's buffer is plenty full, it will put backpressure on the stream, which closes the TCP window size to zero `0`, signaling to the server to stop sending data for a bit.  After a couple minutes in this state, the server may close the connection.  When the browser thinks it wants more data, it will just seamlessly reconnect.

TL;DR;, don't worry about it, it's all figured out for you and works automatically!